# C# equivalent for ByteArrayOutputStream in java

Tags: c#, java, windows-phone-8, stream

I have `java` code as

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos.write(tokenBytes);
baos.write(signedData);
byte[] finalout = baos.toByteArray();
```

where tokenBytes and signedData are byte arrays.In `c#` I have written as

```
 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(tokenBytes);
                writer.Write(signature);
            }
            finalBytesToSend = stream.ToArray();

        }
```

where tokenBytes , signature  and finaleBytesToSend are byte arrays.

Is it correct?  OR is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You have the code. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably I assume you are writing a Java-C# serialization scheme. I think there are 3 things you might want to be careful:

1. That Java byte array output might contain special deliminator at the end.
2. That Java by default using Big-Endian encoding if your data in the byte array wasn't originally just bytes; while C# default is Little Endian encoding.
3. That for strings Java is using UTF-16 (Big Endian) and C# UTF-16 by default is Little Endian.

In my opinion if you are transferring data between Java and C#, you'd better use simply ByteBuffer in Java side and MemoryStream/BinaryReader/BinaryWrite in C# side. Setting UTF-16 Big Endian correctly in C# side, and write your own de-serializer for stuff like int/long/double primitives. That makes it work.

Comment: It's better to use portable serialization format, like XML, JSON, or Protocol Buffers...of course, if OP doesn't tries to read data from Java application, which can't be modified.

Comment: @Dennis Yes and no. Depends on what data he wants to handle and how frequent. Since he's looking at byte arrays, I assume performance and GC matters in this case, which put all XML/JSON/Protocol Buffer in embarrassing situation. Some people might think Protobuf high performance, but if you look at its Java implementation, a lot of temp objects are generated during serialization process. Of course if performance isn't a concern, anything is OK - but I doubt the OP would look at byte format in the first place.

Comment: @Alex How should I proceed then? I didn't get what you told. Can you provide any link for reference?

Comment: @Vaibhav Basically if your data is purely byte data, better use a ByteBuffer; if your data is actually some data you need to decode e.g. strings ints doubles etc, you need to set encoding correctly as well as your own primitive (int/double) reader.